# Does boost directory_iterator visit files and folders in alphabetical order on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I have a folder `fold` with subfolders `sub1`, `sub2`... `subX`, with *unique* files inside.

Let's say I need to find the first occurrence of file X.

All I need is to get a `fold` iterator that goes though `subX` in order or get a list of folders and order it myself. I ran it a couple of times and I noticed that the iterator is indeed going in alphabetical order, however, I could not find it specified on the documentation, so it might be a coincidence. I see however:

> The Linux listing isn't sorted. That's because the ordering of directory iteration is unspecified. Ordering depends on the underlying operating system API and file system specifics. So we need to sort the results ourselves.

- Nothing on Windows (makes me wonder)

EDIT: Files in `fold` are always generated in alphabetical order, in case that changes anything...

#### Question:

Can I trust that it is always going to iterate in order? Does Windows' "*underlying operating system API*" specify order? Based on this article: [What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603), I would not think so.

Comment: Even if the current file system did, nextwork shares are far less likely to, and the next iteration of the OS; well, all bets are off.  Are you expecting over a million subdirectories?  If not, getting the list and sorting is going to be pretty cheap.  Will you support that?  First, I assume, is alphabetical by your specs?

Comment: Uhm... At most 5 subdirectories. I understand what you mean. While it seems to be working, I could not ensure it would stand - or if windows would always work the same way (if that was even a current way). Thank you

Comment: Note that Windows does [fancy sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) of filenames by default, but IIRC, it can be turned off in the registry. So, as Yakk says, you cannot assume a particular sort order. Moreover, if you simply call `std::sort` for instance, the result might be different from what Windows produces with `StrCmpLogicalW`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::filesystem` will be implemented in terms of `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` on windows.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea) of these functions states:

> The order in which the search returns the files, such as alphabetical order, is not guaranteed, and is dependent on the file system. If the data must be sorted, the application must do the ordering after obtaining all the results.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I trust that it is always going to iterate on order?

The [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) says:

> The order of directory entries obtained by dereferencing successive increments of a directory_iterator is unspecified.

Therefore **no**, you can never trust that it is ever going to iterate in order.

If you need a specific order, then you can store the entries into a container, sort it, and then iterate the container.

---

PS. Same applies to `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` as well.

Comment: When I read this I thought it is unspecified because changes based on the OS filesystem. That is why I asked for windows specially - as Linux is stated to be non-functional.

Comment: @MTLaurentys no guarantees are given in the linked documentation for any system.